# Why arctan equal to -90 degrees?

Tags: signal-processing

Can somebody show me why 
$$-\arctan\left(\frac{2\pi}{1-\cos(2\pi)}\right)$$
equals to $-90^\circ$ degrees? Thanks.

Comment: $\cos (2\pi) = 1$, so you have an infinity as the argument of $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: Plus, the $\arctan$ of anything lies strictly between $-90$ and $+90$ degrees. It looks very much like this was originally a statement about limits that got "simplified", so to say. Is that so?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;1-\cos 2\pi=0\;$ the argument isn't defined, but I guess the intention here is

$$\lim_{x\to 2\pi}-\arctan\frac{2\pi}{1-\cos x}=-\frac\pi2$$

since we know $\;\tan x\xrightarrow[x\to\frac\pi2\,^-]{}\infty\;$

Comment: I see it this way @GitGud: $$\frac{2\pi}{1-\cos x}\xrightarrow[x\to 2\pi]{}+\infty\implies\,-\arctan\left(\frac{2\pi}{1-\cos x}\right)\xrightarrow[x\to 2\pi]{}-\frac\pi2 $$ precisely because of what you say...

Comment: Close to, and to the left of $\;\pi/2\;$, both $\;\sin\,,\,\cos\;$ are positive, so tangent *must* be non-negative there...!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you with these wrong trivialities, I visualized it completly wrong.You're right, of course.

Comment: Welcome to the " Rats, I read something yet I understood something else!" club, @GitGud: I'm honorary president.

Comment: $\ddot \smile{}$